# QtQuick Dual Screen support

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I need In My **QtQuick2** application to support multi screen with same resolution. In other word i need to extend my application when i sense secondary screen connected. is it possible in QtQuick2?

Comment: Can you do the same with any other application on your system?

Comment: Yes In visual c++, c#, java ... it is possible

Comment: And what problem do you observe?

Comment: i need to implement this feature in qml and qtquick, I didn’t find any thing in qml/qtquick

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the QtQuick.Window [Screen QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html) to detect multiple monitor setups.

While I don't know if this meet your specific needs you could start out by having a property telling you if you are in a multi-monitor environment:

```
property bool multiMonitor: (Screen.desktopAvailableWidth > Screen.width) ? true : false
```

... maybe start out from there?

[Screen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html) has properties you could use for detecting any further needs your application might have :)

Comment: it is correct but is it possible to full screen on both of them

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want your application to "spilt" into separate windows (that can go into full screen) if more screens are present? If this is the case I guess you could write a "launcher" that detects the monitor setup and then launches a "satelite" app for each monitor. You could let the "satelites" communicate via the "launcher" by IPC to let them decide what to show - each "satelite" would be the same executable started with different parameters. If I'm completely off - please add more information to your original question - I'm a bit uncertain what you're asking

Comment: If you just wan't your application window to span multiple screens you can just set the `width:` of your window item property to `Screen.desktopAvailableWidth` - but I'm not sure that's what you're asking

Comment: It's possible to go full screen on all screens - if you use the "satelite" idea, yes